How can i center my navbar , cant seem to find where the prob is on my css and html?
I'm struggling to get the nav bar to go to the right of my header, it sits right below my logo.


.primary-header{ /*Main top header with navbar*/
    display: flex;
    
}

.primary-header img {  /*Logo properties*/
    width: 184px;
    height: 68px;
}

.topnav a{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
}
<header class = "primary-header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!--Logo top nav bar-->
        <img src ="images/Logo Completo.png" alt="logo1">
        <!--Nav Bar-->
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">                  
            <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
            <a href="#biblioteca">Biblioteca</a>
            <a href="#gaming">Gaming</a>
            <a href="#about">Sobre Mi</a>
            <a href="#contacto">Contacto</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a>
        </div>
    </div>  
</header>




A div is a block element by default, so the .topnav element is by default taking up the full width on its own line.  One approach could be to make it inline-block:


.primary-header{ /*Main top header with navbar*/
    display: flex;
    
}

.primary-header img {  /*Logo properties*/
    width: 184px;
    height: 68px;
}

.topnav {
    display: inline-block;
}

.topnav a{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
}
<header class = "primary-header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!--Logo top nav bar-->
        <img src ="images/Logo Completo.png" alt="logo1">
        <!--Nav Bar-->
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">                  
            <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
            <a href="#biblioteca">Biblioteca</a>
            <a href="#gaming">Gaming</a>
            <a href="#about">Sobre Mi</a>
            <a href="#contacto">Contacto</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a>
        </div>
    </div>  
</header>



Another approach could be to make the .wrapper parent element a flex container, which opens up a variety of flex styling options:


.primary-header{ /*Main top header with navbar*/
    display: flex;
    
}

.primary-header img {  /*Logo properties*/
    width: 184px;
    height: 68px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.topnav a{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    float: left;
    color: black;
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
}
<header class = "primary-header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!--Logo top nav bar-->
        <img src ="images/Logo Completo.png" alt="logo1">
        <!--Nav Bar-->
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">                  
            <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
            <a href="#biblioteca">Biblioteca</a>
            <a href="#gaming">Gaming</a>
            <a href="#about">Sobre Mi</a>
            <a href="#contacto">Contacto</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a>
        </div>
    </div>  
</header>



